# C++11 declaration `::T i`?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is the following C++11 translation unit well-formed?

```
typedef int T;
::T i;
```

If so, it doesn't appear to match the standard grammar.

The `simple-type-specifier` should match `::T`, but the grammar is:

```
simple-type-specifier:
    nested-name-specifier_opt type-name
```

and a `nested-name-specifier` cannot match `::` alone, so `simple-type-specifier` cannot match `::T`.

Is this a standard defect?

Comment: Sorry if this is wrong but doesn't `::identifier` refer to a (qualified) `identifier` in the global namespace?

Comment: "`nested-name-specifier` cannot match `::`" - since you seem sure of this, you should include the explanation for why it can't match in your question.

Comment: @H2CO3 You are correct sir!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a specification defect.  It is fixed in the latest draft, [N3691](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3691.pdf) (PDF), where *nested-name-specifier* is:

```
nested-name-specifier:
    ::
    type-name ::
    namespace-name ::
    decltype-specifier ::
    nested-name-specifier identifier ::
    nested-name-specifier templateopt simple-template-id ::
```

(In C++11, the first production, *nested-name-specifier* -> `::`, is missing.)

Comment: Cheers James, we're working off N3485 so this explains it.  Thanks.

Comment: We should also note here that `qualified-id` was also effected by the fix, as it no longer needs the special cases for single `::` prefixes, so those cases were removed.

Answer (score 1):

So, in addition to **the** answer, merely as clarification: `::identifier` refers to a (qualified) identifier in the global namespace. So **yes, the code in question is actually well-formed.**